# Tweepy not retrieving older mentions

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm on an academic twitter API license and I am trying to retrieve older mentions of particular users using Tweepy. When I add my start_time en end_time parameters to the query for a random user ID (in this case twitter.com/twitter), I get an empty response object that doesn't contain a single tweet. How can I get this to work?

```
# Replace with time period of your choice
start_time = '2017-01-01T00:00:00Z'

# Replace with time period of your choice
end_time = '2017-01-31T00:00:00Z'

mentions = client.get_users_mentions("783214", start_time=start_time, end_time=end_time, max_results=10)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Twitter API v2?

Comment: Yes, as in: I've set up client using tweepy.Client("bearertoken").

Answer (score 1):

The `GET /2/users/:id/mentions` endpoint (which is used by the `get_users_mentions` method) can return only the last 800 mentions. You can read that in the API documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-mentions).

But since you have an academic access, you can use the `GET /2/tweets/search/all` endpoint (with the Tweepy `search_all_tweets` [method](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_all_tweets)) to search for the public mentions of the user.

You can find help to build your query in the Twitter API documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/integrate/build-a-query).